# Convert array to hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class A 
end

class B 
end

a1 = A.new
a2 = A.new
b1 = B.new
b2 = B.new

array = [a1, a2, b1, b2]
hash = {}

array.each do |obj|
    if hash[obj.class] = nil
        hash[obj.class] = []
    else
        hash[obj.class] << obj
    end
end
```

I want hash to be equal to

```
{ A => [a1,a2], B => [b1,b2] }
```

but it's telling me I can't use the `<<` operator.

Comment: Hey bruh, what about using two equals instead of one for your condition.

Comment: I end up with {A => [a2], B => [b2]}

Comment: If there is one thing that every Ruby developer must learn, it’s understanding and debugging “NoMethodError: undefined method for nil:NilClass“ errors themselves.

Comment: @mikeglaz Hey bruh, I am glad to hear that. What about you replace your `else` with an `end` and remove one of the `end` at the end? If the class key does not exist you initialize it and because of the else go right to the next loop so you are missing the first value. a1 and b1.

Comment: @oldergod yes that did it,

Answer (score 2):

Let's sum it up.

```
if hash[obj.class] = nil
```

↑ you are resetting your pair every time your condition runs because of the unique equal that set `hash[obj.class]` to `nil` instead of testing its nillity. Use `==` instead.
Then, you are doing

```
array.each do |obj|
  if hash[obj.class] == nil
    hash[obj.class] = []    # if nil, initialize to new array
  else                      # but because of the else, you are not...
    hash[obj.class] << obj  # doing this so you don't register the first object of each class.
  end
end
```

**Conclusion**

```
array.each do |obj|
  hash[obj.class] ||= [] # set hash[obj.class] to [] if nil (or false)
  hash[obj.class] << obj
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is what you're looking for:

```
# ...

array = [a1, a2, b1, b2]
hash = array.group_by(&:class)
# => {A=>[#<A:0x0000000190dbb0>, #<A:0x000000018fa470>],
#     B=>[#<B:0x000000018e5fe8>, #<B:0x000000018daa80>]}
```

(And as noted in the comments, the error you're getting is because you're setting `hash[obj.class]` to `nil` when you meant to test for equality with `==`.)

Comment: yes, thanks, I need to use == but I also can't use group_by.  I need to do it with something like I have written.

Comment: @mikeglaz `group_by` does exactly what you're looking for... Why can't you use it?  Is this a homework assignment?